# Recursively grabbing parent nodes - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 5 nodes. A Great Grandparent, Grandparent, parent, child 1, child 2.

I have the parent node which is `node_id = 10`. I would like to return the entire hierarchy. I wrote this function which recursively grabs everything below the given node, but I can't find a keyword that is opposite `Prior` to go up the node structure.

```
Select node_id, name, Parent_node_id, Prior name
From my_schema.my_table
Start With node_id = '10'
Connect by Prior node_id = parent_node_id;
```

This is being done through Oracle.

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all database

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza. It's being done through Oracle. I added to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move prior to the other side of the `connect by` cluase:

```
Select node_id, name, Parent_node_id, Prior name
From my_schema.my_table
Start With node_id = '10'
Connect by node_id = prior parent_node_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a different keyword.  To go up the hierarchy, just invert `node_id` and `parent_node_id` in the `connect by` clause:

```
Select node_id, name, Parent_node_id, Prior name
From my_schema.my_table
Start With node_id = '10'
Connect by Prior parent_node_id = node_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense although I think your code is a copy of mine, not the inverse.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My answer has `Connect by Prior parent_node_id = node_id`, while your query has `Connect by Prior node_id = parent_node_id`. The columns are inverted.